# jquery vertical align 2 divs

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I have a fluid tooltip and a button. Their width is determined by the text and div padding. The text can vary. That said how would it be possible to vertically align them via Jquery?

The reason I want to use jquery is to avoid using tables and excessive HTML.

I tried the width() function but it doesn't give the exact width. I suppose one should get the padding too?

Lastly, I'm terrible with numbers.. I'm not sure what formula can be used but I suspect maybe dividing both div widths by 2 and somehow centering the middles?

EDIT: When clicking the button, the tooltip appears and is absolute not to interfere/push other divs.

EDIT: Work in progress  jsfiddle.net/Aezb6

Comment: Do you mean *horizontally* align them ?

Comment: @user , when you click push div you get the thank you for pusing as call out right, if so let me know it should be easy only

Comment: @gov yes you get the pop-up tooltip when clicking the button I should mention that the tooltip is absolute, so it doesn't interfere with other divs.

Comment: @user , i gave you some solution , please try that.

Comment: re-tagged with css.  @user: can you clarify your question? do you mean horizontal alignnment? can you post some code?

Comment: @sebastian , i think he wants the callout to be always centered to the push div... , he is saying callout div is dynamic...width

Comment: @user: i tweaked yr code, just divided `center_it` by 2, see example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the width of the calloutdiv//

`widthCallout=$('#calloutdivWidth');` // this is dynamic

divide this by width of push button which is constant.

get  left :

```
left= widthCallout/pushbuttonwidth
```

you can play around with paddingLeft value + or - which gives you exactly the center :

Comment: the width of the push button is also dynamic, its text varies

Comment: @user , as this is absolutely positioned change it to left property

Comment: @user no problem , thats why you should get the width dynamically ,but you can not make width grow dynamically , you should provide that with some width,

Comment: @user , there are some callout jquery plugins already availabe try those, they will take care of positioning etc. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/YACOP

Comment: lol I wish I knew earlier, I think I'll use the plugin. Anyways here is what I did so far :) http://jsfiddle.net/Aezb6/

Comment: @user , now play around with + or - on the left ...you should be good

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
var item = $(".tooltip");
var container = $("#container");

var position = item.position();

var mytop = position.top - container.height() + $(document).scrollTop();
var myleft = position.left - container.width() + $(document).scrollLeft();

// Correct relative coordinates for IE and WebKIT
if($.browser.msie || $.browser.webkit){
    mytop = position.top - container.height();
    myleft = position.left - container.width();
}

container.offset({top: mytop, left: myleft});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/Aezb6/1/

you just needed to divide `center_it` by 2 to get the halfway point of the tooltip.