# Prevent block element from overflowing parent element's width

Tags: html, css, layout, menu, submenu

I have a menu ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3uCs/)) which displays like below, it is built from `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

[image]

The child menu elements show up below the parent element, and the container is a fixed-width `<ul>`. The problem I have is that for menu element further to the right, this second-level `<ul>` overflows the parent element's width, like so:

[image: Current state]

How can I make sure that the **submenu** shows up as in the first picture, but for menu elements further right just **moves no further than to the right border**, keeping the size intact, instead of overflowing?

[image]

Comment: I think its more easy to write it than to edit yours I had this answer check it please .[**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938038/trying-to-add-a-css-sub-sub-menu/15959920#15959920) and also [_this_](http://jsfiddle.net/D9X6b/)

Answer (score 4):

add to your container overflow-x (you want to keep the y perhaps...) hidden..

```
#navigation{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px 0 13px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    background:#3b6daa;
    overflow-x:hidden; <------------------------------- note the X..
}
```

or just make sure your menu isn't fixed width:

```
#navigation>ul li ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left:auto; 
    top:42px;
    display: none;
    width:auto;   <------------------- will make it adjust to the contain and the content
    background: #81abdd;
    color: #1c508e;
    list-style: none;
}
```

or if you want to align it different (like a tooltip that aligns to the right or left of the parent..then I suggest you go down the javascript path..)

Here are some examples:

examples of aligning
[jquery vertical align 2 divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240218/jquery-vertical-align-2-divs)

jQuery position (also check out width etc)
http://api.jquery.com/position/

a great tooltip that aligns all around
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

No out of the box example, but this should give you the right direciton I believe..

Comment: Thanks for the update. This will solve the overflowing part, but it won't keep the menu its original size.

Comment: the first part will..I understand you want to move the whole menu to the left right, so it will be align differently to the parent?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the submenu should keep its size. Can you somehow accomplish that?

Comment: you want to move the whole submenu to align differently to the parent..sounds like js would be your route rather than just css I believe..I suggest you look at using jQuery to measure the viewPort and the parent stuff, then align it..

Comment: I use jQuery. Can you somehow accomplish that using JavaScript?

Comment: Please see my answer. It can be accomplished in pure css.

Answer (score 2):

You can add parent div to all of your elements with `overflow: hidden;`.

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LgsWP/)

Comment: Can I somehow make sure that the element keeps it's size?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your container:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

You also need to add a height to it that will so that it will display the submenu.

To move certain sub-menu's further left, you need to add a class to their `<ul>` element and then add css to target them and move them as far left as you want:

Ex: if you add the class `push_left` to the submenu `<ul>` element, you can then target it like so:

```
#navigation>ul li .push_left {

    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0px; /* set this value to however far left you want the sub-menu */

}
```

Comment: It's not that easy. Can you make sure that the element is actually moved to the left, instead of just cutting off the overflowing part?

Comment: I would also suggest to use overflow-x (not the y part of it..)

Comment: `overflow-x` somehow cuts off the remainder of the submenu. It doesn't move the submenu to the left to keep it at it's size.

Comment: Edited answer to show how to move only certain items left. Hope it helps. You obviously need to add a different class for each submenu you want to move left if each will be positioned differently (i.e not all the same distance left).

Comment: I have a dynamic menu. Can I somehow do that without differentiating between elements on the left and the right?

Comment: As indicated above, you only apply the class to whatever submenu ul elements you wish to move left.

Comment: @DoryZidon I'd like to keep all menu elements with the same style.

Comment: likeitliekit..I got that..that is why css only with not work, jQuery and some tinkering..have a look at hte links I setn you. @BIOS gotchya, but still you need to measure to know when to push right or left as it also depends sometimes on the viewport or device..

Comment: If the parent container is a fixed width pure css is fine. The example uses a fixed width 900px container so the above will work perfectly in this case.